# Is Opal-based full disk encryption fully working for Linux?

Tags: linux, ssd, opal-2.0

I'd like to know   to manage the password purely via the BIOS and not need to run any utility e.g. sedutil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if your BIOS can handle an Opal SED, then, yes it will work for Linux. Check your BIOS to see if it supports Opal.

Second, SED's protect against someone stealing your computer when it is powered off. In a sleep state, the SED is still drawing power and therefore exposed. So if an attacker steals your computer and wakes it from the sleep state, they potentially have access to all your data.

Third, tools like sedutil make SED's independent of the BIOS. They are no more intrusive than BIOS solutions in that they ask for a password at boot time and then get get out of the way. The only drawback is that they take more effort to install than a pure BIOS solution.

At this time, sedutil will work with any BIOS that does not cut power to the SED during a reboot.